# Can I make JAXB use XmlElementWrapper automatically on every unannotated list it encounters?

Tags: xml, jaxb, moxy

I have a deeply nested third party lib that exposes many POJOs. Furthermore, we have a class structure on our side that uses those POJOs. We've annotated our classes with JAXB annotations to generate XSD and validate XML against that XML as well as parse that XML back into the class structure.

Our code uses the third party code extensively and this third party code needs to part of the the XML validating and parsing process. I cannot annotate their source code. This is per se not a problem, since JAXB can handle unannotated fields in those classes well.

The only problem I encounter now is that lists are not treated as I expected them to be treated. If I have a `List<SomeType> someTypes;` field in one of the third party classes, then JAXB will not generate a wrapper but instead I have to use several "someTypes" tags each indicating a *single* entry of the entire list.
So instead of writing

```
<someTypes>first entry</someTypes>
<someTypes>second entry</someTypes>
```

I would like to write

```
<someTypes>
   <someType>first entry</someType>
   <someType>second entry</someType>
</someTypes>
```

This behaviour is normally achieved using the XmlWrapperElement annotation but I don't have access to the sources.

Is there any way to have JAXB use XmlWrapperElement by default on those inaccessible List fields? I don't want to use MOXy and add annotations for each of those List fields manually in MOXy's external config file.

I've tried using an XMLAdapter but it fails to work since a class can have multiple List fields and the XMLAdapter would only allow one XML tag name for all those fields which would also have to be the same on all lists etc.